# Remote Desktop Connection expels after one hour session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We have a server with Windows Server 2016 in which users access it remotely via a Remote Desktop Connection.
Several users were created to use this access method and when tested in my machine it works with all of the users except the last 2 ones created.
In these 2 last cases the users can enter the serve but it gives a message of 1 hour remaining time from which afterward will be kicked out from server. This is weird since it is allowed access per machine and not by user and this message just shows in accesses from those 2 machines but it works in all other machines to that remote server with same login credentials.
All computers have Windows 10 installed.
At the time of the message the user limit is far to be reached (15 of a total 20).
Already checked Group Policy ans all seems fine, nothing shows why this behavior.

Had this happened to anyone else?

Cheers,
Goncalo

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, go to RD Licensing Manager and took out 2 machines that knew were old and not connecting anymore.
Usually the license is valid for a machine for around 2 months.
Hope it helps any one else out there.